# How to cast after using yield keyword

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to use the `Yield` keyword in a return statement but after using it I have a problem of cast :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'IEnumerable - Mderator' to
> 'Moderator'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
> missing a cast?)

When I delete the `Yield` keyword , I don't have the error , and I don't want using `dynamic` as type return.

This is my Method :

```
        public IEnumerable<Moderator> GetAllModerators(int id)
    {
        RtcRepository repoRtc = new RtcRepository(db);
        yield return repoRtc.GetByID(id).Collection1.SelectMany(x => x.Collection2.Select(y => y.Moderator));
    }
```

Comment: *"I want to use the `Yield` keyword in a return statement"* - actually, you don't. Not for what you've shown, anyway. When you remove it, if you don't get an error, what's the problem?

Comment: @madreflection I don't want remove it but when i remove it i said it works , i don't have an error , after adding it i have the problem of the cast

Comment: Again, you don't want it. `yield return` can only yield one element. To perform `yield return` on a whole collection, you need to iterate the collection, such as with a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the use of yield return.
yield return is used to generate an IEnumerable from multiple successive returns of a basic type.

For instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   yield return i;
```

will generate an IEnumerable.

Here you already have an enumeration so you don't need yield at all.

Answer (score 0):

you don' t need yield in this case. Try this

```
 public IEnumerable<Moderator> GetAllModerators(int id)
 {
        RtcRepository repoRtc = new RtcRepository(db);
      return repoRtc.GetByID(id).Collection1
     .SelectMany(x => x.Collection2.Select(y => y.Moderator)).FirstOrDefault();
  }
```

Comment: Where did `FirstOrDefault` come from?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Query has select list inside of another lit. Sometimes  it  return result  as a List of List. In this case it is useful.